# Eliminate useless repeats of values from CSV for line charting

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

Given a CSV file with contents similar to this:

```
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP3,GRP3,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP3,GRP3,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:21,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
```

What is the best way using bash or awk scripting to tidy it up and remove all useless zeros.  By useless I mean: this data will be used for line charts in web pages.  However reading the entire CSV file in the web browser via JavaScript/jQuery etc is very slow.  It would be more efficient to eliminate the useless zeros prior to uploading the file.  If I remove all the zeros, the lines all more or less show peak to peak to peak instead of real lines from zero to some larger value back to zero, followed by a space until the next value greater than zero.

As you see there are 3 groups in the list of data. Any time there are 3 in a row for example for GRP1, I'd like to remove the middle or 2nd 0 in that list.  In reality, this could work for values greater than zero also...if the same values were found every 10 seconds for say 10 in a row... it would be good to leave both ends in place and remove items 2 through 9.

The line chart would look the same, but the data would be much smaller to deal with.  Ideally I could do this with a shell script on disk prior to reading the input file.

So (just looking at GRP1) instead of:

```
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:21,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:31,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:41,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:51,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:01:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,2
```

The script would eliminate all useless 3 values...and leave only:

```
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:51,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:01:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,2
```

Or... Another Expected Result using 0 this time...instead of 3 as the common consecutive value for GRP2...

```
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:21,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:31,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:41,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:51,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:01:01,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,2
```

The script would eliminate all useless 0 values...and leave only:

```
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:51,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:01:01,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,2
```

@karakfa answer gets me close but still end up with portions similar to this after applying awk to one unique group and then eliminating some duplicates that also showed up for some reason:

I like it but it still ends up with this:

```
2017-05-02,00:05:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,2
2017-05-02,00:06:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:06:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:07:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:07:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:08:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:08:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:09:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:09:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:10:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:10:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:11:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:11:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:12:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:12:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:13:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:13:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:14:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:14:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:15:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:15:11,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:15:21,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,9
```

Would be wonderful to get to this instead:

```
2017-05-02,00:05:51,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,2
2017-05-02,00:06:01,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:15:11,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,1
2017-05-02,00:15:21,DTE,DTE,TOTAL,9
```

Comment: at least, show the expected output

Comment: Please add expected output for the given input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one ill-placed question but I'll take a crack at the title, if you don't mind:

```
$ awk -F, ' {
    if($3 OFS $4 OFS $6 in first)
        last[$3 OFS $4 OFS $6]=$0
    else 
        first[$3 OFS $4 OFS $6]=$0 }
END { 
    for(i in first) {
        print first[i]
        if(i in last)
            print last[i] } 
}' file
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:21,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP3,GRP3,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP3,GRP3,TOTAL,0
```

Basically it keeps the first and last (if exists) occurrence of each unique combination of 3rd, 4th and 6th field.

**Edit**: In the new light of the word *consecutive*, how about this awful hack:

```
$ awk -F, '
(p!=$3 OFS $4 OFS $6) {
    if(NR>1 && lp<(NR-1))
        print q
    print $0
    lp=NR }
{
    p=$3 OFS $4 OFS $6
    q=$0 }
' file
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP3,GRP3,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP3,GRP3,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:21,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
```

and output for the second data:

```
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:51,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:01:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,2
```

and the third:

```
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:00:51,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,0
2017-05-01,00:01:01,GRP2,GRP2,TOTAL,2
```

Comment: I agree, it's not the clearest question. Sorry about that.  Your answer is impressive, for first and last of unique values per group for the overall file.  Now the trick is going to be applying it to only sections of consecutive same values prior to a value change. So it may partially get me there.

Comment: If I first create a file for a unique group (1 of the 3) then apply your awk, it seems to work well. Thanks.  Still validating.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F, '$NF!=0' inputfile
```

The output:

```
2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:11,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:21,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
```

---

`$NF!=0` - takes into account only those lines which don't have `0` as their last field value

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that eliminates ALL zeros, not just the "useless" ones in my example.  I wish to keep some.  Especially any that are end points to many consecutive of the same value, so they still get charted/graphed as 0 to 0... without needing all the 0's in between both ends...for a given GRP.

Comment: @CJoe, what does mean *to keep some* ? you have posted the expected result in which you had not kept some

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[,:]' '$4==pt+10 && $NF==p {pt=$4; pl=$0; next} 
                pl                  {print pl} 
                                    {pt=$4;p=$NF}1' file

2017-05-01,00:00:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:00:51,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,3
2017-05-01,00:01:01,GRP1,GRP1,TOTAL,2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not seeing repeats eliminated and the resulting file ends up larger than the file I start with.

Comment: did you try the script with the sample inputs you provided?

Comment: If I grep first to get 1 unique GRP, then apply your awk it works ok, eliminating 4 of 6 per minute readings. But for example from 00:06:01 to 00:15:11 in my sample file here, all are value 1 for GRP1.  There are still 20 rows.  Would be nice to only have 2.  First and Last... prior to value change.

Comment: it means your sample data is not representative of your real case.  Here all the records are of the same type and sorted, which is the backbone of the solution proposed.